# Implement windows azure service bus topics/subscription in MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, servicebus

Here is the scenario:
We are implementing an application which allows users to "communicate" with an endpoint on premises. We are doing some research and **Windows Azure Service Bus Topics** seems to be a good choice since it helps us to create bi-directional communication & helps us to solve issue with firewalls, NAT devices. 
However, as the user interact with the machines via a stateless web app (in this case is MVC 3), re-creating **TopicClient** on every request is unaccepted. 
Since each user has his own endpoint, sharing one **TopicClient** as someone suggested is also doesn't work. 
Another approach is using **session** to keep the TopicClient for each user, but using session seems isn't a good choice for stateless and hosted on Windows Azure web app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm little bit lost as to what you are describing, your first scenario is talking about service bus relay, hosting on premises WCF Services exposed via the SB endpoint that can be consumed from clients via the SB. Your second part talks about Topics/Subscriptions, in this case you would create a BrokerMessage on your client and then have a Subscription (Pub/Sub Model) read that message (based on the number of subscribers) from a durable Service Bus Queue, can you explain which scenario you want to use?

Comment: Sorry for making your confusion. The first scenario is exactly what I want (I just confused myself with Topics/Subscriptions). Currently, a client must be created and connected to the SB every time a request to the SB is made, that is slow. Therefore, I would like to create an instance of the SB client when user is logged in, then re-use the instance for the whole session. However, some people suggest session is a good practice for windows Azure service. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

The actual connection between the client and the Service exists at the MessagingFactory level, all the TopicClient objects created from that factory will share the same connection. Thus you can just cache the MessagingFactory and/or as many TopicClients as you need. In addition these objects are thread safe so can be shared and used by different consumers concurrently.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek for your answer. However, the application I'm implementing is a web app, there for caching objects is also a big trouble. Do you have any suggestion how should I cache those objects? Thanks